# Gradient effect in button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have try below xml code but I do not get output as in image.

```
<item  >
    <shape>
        <gradient
           android:startColor= "#AE845c"
           android:endColor="#935Fc0"

             />


    </shape>
</item>
```

I want like this .

[image]

Comment: use <solid></solid> tag and then specify your gradient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add angle

```
<item  >
    <shape>
        <gradient
           android:angle="90"
           android:startColor= "#bc9b78"
           android:endColor="#7c4727"

             />


    </shape>
</item>
```

if it's not working please put code where you are using this.

Comment: @NiravRanpara i have edited with color code.we are not here to solve ur exact problem.something u shud do.

Comment: This work but see image between image there is line effect . can you know how to do that ?

Comment: @NiravRanpara i dont think it is possible through shape gradient.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21499/discussion-between-nirav-ranpara-and-android-killer)

Answer (score 2):

Use android type and angle for gradient. Change angle value from 0 to 360 as per your requirement.

```
android:type="linear"
android:angle="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
       <gradient android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF" android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:angle="225"/> 

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

you can try this...

Comment: just take angle = 90  in your case